# Python: mysql double and float

Tags: python, mysql, floating-point, double, decimal

In MySQL table column **balance** has a type DOUBLE without specifying precision. And I can't change column type to DECIMAL or DOUBLE with precision (I know that is epic fail to store money in DOUBLE column, but can't to change something)

If in Python I need to update a balance column, e.g. increase this value (`balance = balance + 10/29`), should I simply add that Python's float value, or I need to add `balance = Decimal(balance) + Decimal(10/29)` to avoid loss in accuracy? DOUBLE is a float type, DECIMAL - not. I think I need to add a DECIMAL value. Am I right? Or in the future I still will have problems with accuracy?

Comment: Monetary data should be stored as decimal. ***.***

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks. i.e. if MySQL column has a DOUBLE type, I will still have problems in accuracy even if I will calculate balance in Python as decimal?

Comment: Yes. E.g. converting 100 + 10/29 to 4 digit decimal gives you 100.3448, when you store it as a double in MySQL it becomes 100.3448028564453125

Comment: "10/29"?  That does not sound like "money".  For "money", use `DECIMAL`; for "scientific" values, use `DOUBLE`.

Comment: @RickJames Hi. It's a money / currency rate